Clip function for QGIS plugin is not accurate
I am trying to build a QGIS plugin using QGIS 3.28.14, python 3.9 and in VS code environment. The problem is that when I use Native: Clip function, the resulted file has smaller area than the area I used as an overlay to clip the input. Not to mention both input and overlay files are shapefiles and they are in the same coordinate system. I used the original clip function from the 'Geoprocessing Tools' on both of the data. The total area of the result is the same as the overlay layer. I couldn't find any problems so far. The result from my plugin is not so far from the result from 'clip' function. I want to increase the accuracy of the result. What should I do? I have uploaded my code below:
parameters = {
            'INPUT': input_layer.source(),
            'OVERLAY': clip_layer.source(),
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT  
        }
    
        context = QgsProcessingContext()
        feedback = QgsProcessingFeedback()

        # Execute the algorithm
        try:
            result = processing.run("native:clip", parameters, context=context, feedback=feedback)
            clipped_layer = result['OUTPUT']
            if clipped_layer.featureCount() == 0:
                print("No features were created in the clipping process.")
                return
            print(f"Clipping completed with {clipped_layer.featureCount()} features.")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Clipping failed: {e}")
            return```



If the input feature you clip doesn't fully overlap the feature you clip with, the output area is going to be smaller than the input feature

How can I reduce this issue? I tried geometric correction, set a certain projection but nothing seems work. But when I use the 'Clip' function from the 'Geoprocessing Tools' on the same set of data, the result seems accurate.

That is how clip works, it is not an error. Maybe you want Union or Merge ?

No, I specifically needed the clip function. So far I have increased the accuracy by using fixed geometry tool and also comparing the both layers before clipping. Now the difference between my clip function and the QGIS's native clip function is in down to few meters to the decimals. How can I improve it for more?
